# How can I make a freedom Desktop application using Java

Tags: java, class, exe

I am newbie in Java. I have a little question.
Suppose, I have written a code in Java like this:-

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
public class J02_02 extends Applet
{
    public void paint (Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawString("Make a Software From this Java Code",10,100);
    }
}
```

I have compiled it using `javac` command to a J02_02.class and it's running well in **Java Applet**. But, I want to make a freedom desktop application from this code. Think, I want to make a desktop application like any other software we use IE: Firefox, Notepad, KMPlayer. I mean, I want to run this application to a computer where java isn't installed. I want to make this .class file to an .exe software. The .exe software should run on any platform like windows/linux without installing anything else like Java/jdk.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Ahead Of Time (AOT) compiler is the answer...

A common on AOT compiler would be [Excelsior](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/jet.html).

Comment: Where can I download it from?

Comment: I need an step by step answer including what to do from first to last. Please.

Comment: Note, excelsior does not yet support Java 7, you'll have to recompile the code to Java 6.  You may try a Google search, it may give you some other brands too.

Comment: I am using Java 7. Please find something compatible for Java 7. I am unable to get any.

Comment: I can do, but I know you can provide better solution for this. :)

Answer (score 0):

An AOT compiler is clearly an overkill in your situation.

Check out the other options in my article [Convert Java to EXE: Why, When, When Not and How](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-to-exe.html).

Just in case, Excelsior JET 9 supports Java 7: http://www.excelsiorjet.com